# How does MagicMock avoid throwing AttributeError when a random method is called?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, magicmock

In Python, if you call a method that doesn't exist it throws an AttributeError. Ex

```
>>> class A:
...     def yo(self):
...             print(1)
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.yo()
1
>>> a.hello()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'hello'
```

In the below code, MagicMock class doesn't have a function named hello or no patch was created for a method hello. Still below code doesn't throw an AttributeError

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock 
>>> obj = MagicMock()
>>> obj.hello()
<MagicMock name='mock.hello()' id='4408758568'>
```

How is MagicMock able to do this? How can I create a class that can perform an action when any method (which might not be defined) is called on it?

Comment: [It's magic](http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/mgc.gif). ;)

Comment: I thought there was a special method that got called every time a function is called. And MagicMock overrides that.

Comment: The mock documentation refers to this repeatedly; you need to *spec* the mock if you want to see attribute errors.

Comment: I understand that with autospec=True, it will throw AttributeError. My question is how is MagicMock able to return mock for any method that get's called open it's object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python datamodel documents a hook, [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), which shall be called when attribute access fails to resolve in the usual ways. Mocks use it to return a new mock instance - i.e. mocks define unknown attributes as [*factories*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)).

Reproducing mock's implementation in a simpler way, you would just turn `__getattr__` and `__call__` into factory functions:

```
class M:
    def __call__(self):
        return M()
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return M()
```

Example usage:

```
>>> mock = M()
>>> mock.potato
<__main__.M at 0xdeadbeef>
>>> mock.potato()
<__main__.M at 0xcafef00d>
```

> How is MagicMock able to do this?

This part is not specific to `MagicMock`, an ordinary `Mock` will do the same (the "magic" in the name is just referring to additional features allowing better mocking of [magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup)).  `MagicMock` [inherits such behavior from one of the base classes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e80e77a484983ffb527ef22d336ff9500589dce3/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L575):

```
>>> MagicMock.mro()
[unittest.mock.MagicMock,
 unittest.mock.MagicMixin,
 unittest.mock.Mock,
 unittest.mock.CallableMixin,
 unittest.mock.NonCallableMock,  # <--- this one overrides __getattr__!
 unittest.mock.Base,
 object]
```

> How can I create a class that can perform an action when any method (which might not be defined) is called on it?

It depends if you want to be in front of, or behind, a normal attribute access.  If you want to get in front, you should define [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__), it's called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses before searching the class/instance namespaces. However, if you want to take a lower precedence to normal attributes (i.e. those living in the object `__dict__`) and to [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol), then you should define `__getattr__` as previously discussed.

Comment: Is there a way that Mock or MagicMock itself support pre/post behavior for any method call on the object its mocking? I have a function that holds the responses of my mock object's calls and I'd like any call on that mock to complete with the result of that function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually know how specifically `MagicMock` works (I've never used it, but I've Heard Good Things), but this part of the behaviour can be replicated (along with probably multiple other possible solutions) by hijacking `__getattr__` in a way that it returns a callable that creates a new mock instance when called:

```
class MM:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        # store a name, TODO: random id, etc.
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        # make it pretty
        if self.name:
            r = f'<MM name={self.name}>'
        else:
            r = f'<MM>'
        return r

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        # we want a factory for a mock instance with a name corresponding to attrname
        def magicattr():
            return MM(name=f"'mock.{attrname}()'")
        return magicattr
```

When executed, we see the following:

```
>>> MM()
<MM>
>>> MM().hello()
<MM name='mock.hello()'>
```

I didn't go overboard with defining an `id` and whatnot, but the basic trick can be seen on the above stripped-down example.

The way the above works is that accessing `.hello` or any other attribute goes through our custom `__getattr__` which gives us a chance to generate a fake (mocked) method on the fly, with whatever properties we want to. As I understand one of the many benefits of `MagicMock` is exactly that we don't have to worry about `AttributeError`s being thrown by default, it *just works*.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!

Comment: @2ank3th I suggest changing the accept to wim's answer. I only posted one because people more familiar with the subject didn't seem to bite.